# XFCE - Blue Line Across Screen

Tags: xfce

In my Xubuntu version of Ubuntu, I've recently just been doing my thing, until this blue line popped up. Go to https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgjGw.jpg for the image. Zoom in and look to the right.

If you look closely, you can see a blue line on the right side of my screen. Additional info about my desktop is that I use Plank for the fabulous bar on the bottom of the screen

Comment: please put a fixed color as wallpaper and upload the image again, i cant see a thing in that screen...

Comment: @talktogus Alright, you have to zoom in.

Comment: I have zoomed in too.  I cannot see any line running vertically on the right side.  The only line I see is the horizontal line that extends from left to right probably caused by Plank.

Comment: Really? I can. The line is very small, but I can see it.

Comment: Holy crap! It's not there! @talktogus Woahh... It was on my desktop.

Comment: Related to https://nochkawtf.wordpress.com/2015/05/03/horizontal-line-across-screen-on-xfce/ ?

Comment: @DKBose No, screenshot doesn't capture the line :(

Comment: It's vertical though, and blue.